# closing javascript child window

Tags: javascript, window

```
function displaymessage()
{
window.open("http://www.sabah.com.tr","_blank")

parentWindow.close
}
```

How should I write instead of "parentWindow.close" to close the child page?

Comment: if you close the chid window.. Why are you opening it?

Comment: us mortals can not know this :)

Answer (score 3):

not 100% sure what you mean, maybe you want this:

```
function displaymessage() {
  var win = window.open("http://www.sabah.com.tr","_blank")
  win.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to maintain a reference to the opened window:

```
function displaymessage() {
  var myWin = window.open("http://www.sabah.com.tr","_blank");
  myWin.close();
}
```

..but most browsers will prompt you saying "this page is trying to close....", just be aware of that, and test various browsers to make sure you get the desired result.

Comment: yes working.. and how should i close the window 5 secons later??

Comment: @murat - change `myWin.close();` to `setTimeout(function() { myWin.close(); }, 5000);`

Comment: function displaymessage() {
  var win = window.open("http://www.sabah.com.tr","_blank")
  setTimeout(function() { myWin.close(); }, 5000)
} not working tha child didnt close ant time