# Close child window once loaded in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I'm trying to write a JS/jQuery script that opens a whole load of links from a page in child windows, then closes each child window once it has loaded. This is because once the child page has loaded, it triggers a download, and I then need the child page to close. I've tried a variety of things, but none of them seem to work, perhaps someone can help me?
Here's an example of something I was trying:

```
var imgURL = "http://...etc";
var imgWindow = window.open(imgURL);
imgWindow.ready(function(){
    this.close();
});
```

Would really appreciate any suggestions how to get this to work, bit stuck!

Comment: Would this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4453333/174184) help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will open a new window and closes after that window is loaded.

```
var imgURL = "http://yourdomain.com/imagePage.html";
var imgWindow = window.open(imgURL);
imgWindow.onload = function(){
    imgWindow.close();
};
```

This will work only if the child window is from the same domain. If the URL of the child window is not the same domain, you can't do anything. That would be a XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Ah, I've marked this as correct even though it won't work for what I'm doing as the child window does come from a different domain. I'm loading a set of links from another page onto my own page and then trying to automate a set of downloads. Unfortunately, without closing the windows as it goes it jams up, as I need to be able to download around 2000 files, and it stops opening the windows after about 40 or so... Gonna have to find a different work around I guess...

Comment: why don't you try and zip your files server side and then send it for download! As a user receiving 2000 files as download is very strange!!

Comment: Just to explain what I'm up to (because maybe you can help me!): I'm trying to download raw solar data from a NASA website. They do have a front end for some of this, but it's very restricted. Here is an example page: http://jsoc.stanford.edu/data/aia/images/2012/02/01/171/ Normally I would just select all the links and download them in jDownloader, but jDownloader doesn't work with this links, because rather than the link being the actual image, it seems to direct to a page and then trigger the download. My php/js script is trying to automate a download. I am the only user of this.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code above is that there is not `ready` method for a `window` object.

Try this :

```
var imgURL = "http://google.com";
var imgWindow = window.open(imgURL);
imgWindow.addEventListener('load', imgWindow.close(), true);
```

Comment: This seems to close the new window before any content is loaded.

Comment: Oh is it? That's weird as the listener should work only on load event. Perhaps the page loads super fast!

Comment: You are calling the close method instead of passing it as the event handler. It should be `imgWindow.close.bind(imgWindow)`